# Getting an error while npm install to start React Application

Tags: npm

I am getting errors while npm install. Even I am trying this in admin mode on my window pc. I tried everything but not able to get off from this error.

Firstly I get this as error:-[image]

After working on some suggestions I am getting error as below:-
[image]

After further working on some more suggestions I am getting another error that is shown below:[image]

After trying some more suggestions I am finally getting this as error:-
[image]

Comment: It seems that `bufferutil` needs some binaries. Either there is no prebuilt binary for the Node.js version, that you use or your computer is behind a corporate proxy which blocks the download of the prebuilt binaries. As the script of `bufferutil` is not able to download the prebuilt binaries, it trys to build them locally. But this build fails, because some needed components for the build (like python) is missing.

Comment: So is there any way to solve that??

Comment: There should be a way, however I have never used the `bufferutil` so I don't know exactly how to do it in this concrete case. I had similar issue with `node-sass` behind a corporate proxy. In that case I managed to get the prebuilt binaries from an alternative source, which was accessible.